# Unable to store and manage session in express

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I am new to express and using express-session to manage login(s) in my application.
I have followed a blog and declared my session as below:-

```
app.use(session({
secret:'Keep It Secret',
name : 'uniqueSessionID',
resave : true,
saveUninitialized : true,
cookie : { secure : false, maxAge : 3600000, loggedIn : false, username : "" }
}));
```

The problem is that on a successful login I'm updating the session and printing it, which outputs to:-

```
    Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-12-27T13:16:17.355Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    loggedIn: true,
    username: 'pushkar@gmail.com'
  }
}
```

But after that when I authenticate the routes, the session remains unchanged just like below:-

```
    Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-12-27T13:16:17.355Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
```

I have tried all and need help.

This is my login where I login and make the session:-

```
const login = (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body);
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;

if(email == "" && password == ""){
    req.flash("message","please fill in the required fields");
    res.redirect("/admin/login");
}
else if(email == ""){
    req.flash("message", "please fill in the email");
    res.redirect("/admin/login");
}
else if(password == ""){
    req.flash("message", "please fill in the password");
    res.redirect("/admin/login");
}
else {
    user.findOne({email : email}, function(err, data){
        debugger;
        if(err){
            req.flash("message", "Username not found");
            res.redirect("/admin/login");
        }
        else {
            if(data.password == password){
                req.session.cookie.loggedIn = true;
                req.session.cookie.username = email;
                req.session.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                })
                console.log(req.session);
            }
            else{
                req.flash("message", "Invalid Password");
                res.redirect("/admin/login");
            }
            res.redirect("/admin/dashboard");
        }
    })
}

};
```

and This is my authentication function:-

```
exports.authenticated = (req, res, next) => {
debugger;
console.log(req.session);
if(req.session.cookie.loggedIn) {
    next();
}
else {
    res.redirect("/admin/login");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incorrect to set the value, you want to save, to `req.session.cookie` it the place where you set up `uniqueSessionID` cookie options, not saved value.

See [this tutorial for example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm)

try

```
//to write
req.session.loggedIn = true;
req.session.username = email;

//to read
if(req.session.loggedIn) {
    next();
}
```

if all works, maybe you will want to make the session permanent between restarts, so see next
[Example with permanent storage](https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/#the-bug-alert)

Comment: Sorry For The Late Replies!   And Thanks For The Answer.   :-)